# Completely disable geolocation on Opera 65

Tags: privacy, web-browsing, opera

I would like to completely disable Geolocation (not even get a prompt to be asked to allow it) on Opera 65 on the Mac.

I found [this document](https://help.opera.com/en/geolocation/) on the Opera website which says

> Turning off geolocation
>
> You can reject Google Location Services’ terms and conditions. Alternatively, go to Settings (Preferences on Mac) > Websites > Location, and uncheck Allow websites to request my physical location.

I found several other articles on the web with essentially the same instructions. However, in Opera 65, there is no "Websites" setting header. The only relevant setting I can find is Preferences > Advanced > Site Settings > Location where the only global option I have is "Ask before accessing (recommended)". If I disable that option, then all websites get geolocation data if they want it, without any prompting.

I want to block all requests, or at least go back to the state before I accepted Google Location Services’ terms and conditions. Is that possible?